# how to localise texts fetched by database struts

Tags: localization, struts-1

To localise any text, we do in general

```
 index.jsp

 <!--<span>hello</span>-->
 <span><bean:message key="index.hello"/></span>

 ApplicationResource_en.properties
 index.hello=hello

 ApplicationResource_es.properties
 index.hello=hola
```

My problem is how to localise dynamic text like

```
index.jsp
<span><bean:write "information" property="hello" />
```

Please suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bean:message tag instead of bean:write as following

```
<bean:message bundle= "bundleKey" key= "a.message" />
```

Bundle is the name of the locale